# Setting input for system() calls in ruby

Tags: ruby, system

I'm trying to download a file using net/sftp and pass its contents as the stdin for a command-line app. I can do it by first writing the file to disk but I'd rather avoid that step.

Is there any way to control the input to a program invoked with `system()` in ruby?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't use [`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441) at all for this sort of thing, `system` is best for running an external command that you don't need to talk to.

Use [`Open3.open3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html#M001644) or [`Open3.open2`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/classes/Open3.html#M001645) to open up some pipes to your external process then write to the `stdin` pipe just like writing to any other IO channel; if there is any output to deal with, then you can read it straight from the `stdout` pipe just like reading from any other input IO channel.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps (using open as mu suggested)?

```
contents = "Hello, World!"
open('|echo', 'w') { puts contents }
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished with IO.expect

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

str = "RUBY_VERSION"

PTY.spawn("irb") do |reader, writer|
  reader.expect(/0> /)
  writer.puts(str)
  reader.expect(/=> /)
  answer = reader.gets
  puts "Ruby version from irb: #{answer}"
end
```

This waits for the spawned process to display "0> " (the end of an irb prompt) and when it sees that prints a defined string.  It then looks for the irb to return by waiting for it to display "=> " and grabs the data returned.