# Ruby alternative to passthru() in PHP?

Tags: ruby

What I'm looking for is to execute an interactive script and ask user for input. The input format may vary from times to times the program being called, so I need the original prompt from the callee script and redirect stdin to the callee.

Currently I find that the `passthru()` function in PHP just meets my need. However, is there an alternative to or ways to implement the `passthru()` function?

**UPDATE**

An example (simpler as the real situation) to explain myself:

```
puts `sudo apt-get -y upgrade`
```

The `sudo` command may ask user for password. For `sudo`, the input format remains constant, I could use `popen` for it. However what if the input format of the command being called is very complex and varies from times to times?

Comment: you want to execute a linux command, and get the result back to ruby?

Comment: @VitaliMogilevsky Thx for your reply. Not exactly, I want to execute a command but don't need the output in Ruby. However I need to get the user input and pass them to the command being called.

Comment: Im not 100% sure what are you trying to do, you can read user input by setting param = gets, then use the param anywhere you want. if you want to use it in the command simply use it as regular string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to achieve what you want with [PTY.spawn](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html#method-c-spawn). Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854413/5006469).

Comment: Thanks! Although a little different than what I'm looking for, but still it works for me for now.