# Why isn't standard output displayed from a rake task called via backticks?

Tags: ruby, output, rake, rake-task, backticks

When a rake task is called via backpacks its output is suppressed:

```
task :two do
    puts 'two'
end

task :one do
    puts 'one'
    `rake two`
end 

-bash> bundle exec rake one
one
```

Whereas, the output is displayed when called via `.invoke`:

```
task :one do
    puts 'one'
    Rake::Task['two'].invoke
end 

-bash> bundle exec rake one
one
two
```

Why is the output suppressed with backticks, and how can it be displayed?

The above is a contrived example, but ultimately I want to be able to run a local rake task that itself runs a remote rake task, on Heroku, and I want to see its output in **real time** (because the remote task is **interactive**, i.e. it asks questions via `puts` and waits for user/standard input via `$stdin.gets.chomp`):

```
task :one do
    puts 'one'
    `heroku run rake my_app:reset_user_passwords --app #{MY_APP_NAME}`
end
```

Comment: For interactive tasks, you probably need to refactor with the [pty](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) and [expect](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/pty/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-expect) modules, or simply shell out to Expect directly.

Answer (score 1):

Backticks [return the standard output of command](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Kernel.html#method-i-60) so if you want to see the result, just call `puts`:

```
task :one do
    puts 'one'
    puts `heroku run rake my_app:reset_user_passwords --app #{MY_APP_NAME}`
end
```

If you want a interactive execution, you can try to use [`IO#expect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854180/ruby-interactive-shell-commands)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, I failed to mention that the remote task is *interactive*, so I need to see the output in **real time**, not after the completion of the task. I have updated my question to reflect this.